# Java automatically recognizes thread deadlock and stops execution?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, deadlock

I am working on a Java project to simulate the [dining philosophers problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem).

I started with the basic behavior, where each thread think(), getForks(), eat(), and putForks(). So there's no prevention of deadlocks or starvation (done on purpose).

The getForks() method works like this:

```
getForks(){
    while(forks[rightFork]==0) /*0 means fork is not on the table, so wait*/
         print(Thread #id waiting for right fork);
    forks[rightFork] = 0;
    while(forks[leftFork]==0)
         print(Thread #id waiting for left fork);
    forks[leftFork = 0;
}
```

I put a sleep(5000) between getting the right and the left fork, so the program is running into a deadlock (with each thread holding the right fork). What is unexpected, however, is that for some reason execution is halting once it reaches the deadlock. I expected that the "Thread #id waiting for fork" messages would keep being printed during the deadlock, but they are not. Once deadlock is reached no more messages are printed.

Any clue why?

If you want to see the whole code, here it's:

```
public class Philosophers{
    private static final int NUMBER = 3;
    private static final int MIN_SLEEP = 1000;
    private static final int MAX_SLEEP = 6000;
    private static Thread[] threads = new Thread[NUMBER];
    private static int[] forksArray = new int[8];

    private static void start(){
        System.out.println("Simulation started.");

        //Initialize forks array (1 means on the table)
        for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
            forksArray[i] = 1;

        //Create and start individual threads
        for(int i=0;i<NUMBER;i++){
            threads[i] = new Thread(new Philosopher(i));
            threads[i].start();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                start();
            }
        });
    }

    private static class Philosopher implements Runnable{
        private int id;
        private int leftFork;
        private int rightFork;

        public void run(){
            System.out.println("Thread "+id+" started.");
            while(true){
                think();
                getForks();
                eat();
                putForks();
            }
        }

        public Philosopher(int id){
            this.id = id;
            this.rightFork = id;
            if(id==NUMBER - 1)
                this.leftFork = 0;
            else
                this.leftFork = id + 1;
        }

        public void think(){
            System.out.println("Thread "+id+" thinking...");
            try{
                int sleepInterval = MIN_SLEEP + (int)(Math.random() * ((MAX_SLEEP - MIN_SLEEP) + 1));
                Thread.sleep(sleepInterval);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }

        public void getForks(){
            System.out.println("Thread "+id+" getting forks.");

            //Grab fork on the right
            while(forksArray[rightFork]==0)
                System.out.println("Thread "+id+" waiting for right fork");
            forksArray[rightFork] = 0;  

            try{
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }   
        catch(Exception e){

        }

            //Grab fork on the left
            while(forksArray[leftFork]==0);
            System.out.println("Thread "+id+" waiting for left fork");
            forksArray[leftFork] = 0;           
        }

        public void eat(){
            System.out.println("Thread "+id+" eating.");
            try{
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }

        public void putForks(){
            System.out.println("Thread "+id+" putting forks down.");
            forksArray[rightFork] = 1;
            forksArray[leftFork] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is impossible to tell without seeing the actual code - do you use locks? synchronized blocks?

Comment: @assylias, there you go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is here:

```
while(forksArray[leftFork]==0);
System.out.println("Thread "+id+" waiting for left fork");
```

The ; after the `while()` means it has an empty statement as its body. So, the `println` on the next line will happen only once the loop terminates.

(Incidentally, this is why people often recommend always using {} for loops even if they are single-line)

Comment: That line is fine: it is meant to wait until the value becomes != 0. And the value is updated from another thread

Comment: @assylias Yes, but the question was about why the messages are not being printed. And that's because OP thinks the `println` is the body of the loop, but really the ; is the body of the loop.

Comment: @Russell Zahniser, you nailed it. Basically the messages were not being printed because of that extra ';'. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is not really a deadlock: you don't use any locks! It is simply an infinite loop.

One issue is that you don't use proper synchronization. In particular, the compiler is free to replace:

```
while (forksArray[leftFork] == 0);
```

with:

```
int temp = forksArray[leftFork];
while (temp == 0);
```

And that can happen at anytime during the execution of your program.

Simply making your array volatile:

```
private static volatile int[] forksArray = new int[8];
```

should make this issue disappear. Note however that marking the array volatile only prevents that optimisation from being performed - it is not enough to make the code thread safe.

Comment: My question is not how I can avoid running into the deadlock (I know how to use locks for that purpose). My question is how come the messages stop being printed once it reaches that point. Even if the compiler replaces your suggested code do you agree the messages should keep being printed while the threads keep waiting for the forks? Also, even if you use "volatile" you'll still run into the deadlock with the code I pasted above. Volatile only tells that the variable should not be placed in registers for optimization.

Comment: @DanielS Sorry I quoted the wrong loop - see my edit. When I add volatile, I don't observe the behaviour you mention any more.

Comment: making an array volatile does _not_ make modifying the elements have volatile semantics!  you can use AtomicIntegerArray to do this.  however, that doesn't solve the lack of atomicity problem.

Comment: @Assylias, I updated the code to include a sleep(5000) between getting the right fork and the left one. Add that sleep and you'll see the deadlock and the messages not being printed anymore.

Comment: @jtahlborn I know - but it is enough to prevent the optimisation that was causing the issue. I have added a note to clarify.